# get JSON generated by a webhook hosted onlilne

Tags: node.js

I am making a plagariam check and then it communicates to the server of the company via webhook, the response is then recorded in RequestBin, which generates a JSON response in their website, how do I extract the information from the website to my node js code?

The webpage looks like this: my requestb.in online webhook

What I need is to get that raw JSON.

Comment: Why are you using RequestBin ? Why not make the request, and wait for the server's response ? RequestBin is for dev / testing purpose, not app building.

Comment: i'm new to node js. can you tell me how to do that

Comment: This is not about NodeJS knowledge, but knowing the purpose of the services you are using. It's written on the RequestBin website : "Use RequestBin to see what your HTTP client is sending or to inspect and debug webhook requests." This is clearly testing oriented. Also you have not answered : Why not make the request, and wait for the server's response ?

Comment: _customHeaders[config.HTTP_CALLBACK] = 'https://webhook.site/1c217374-2aaa-4b80-9018-2f24f5414bcb' /........i'm using this line how to change it?

Comment: how to use HTTP-get request? so that i can directly get json data instead of going through requestBin

Comment: Just make an HTTP request (https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) to the server that will check for plagiarism

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get data via API from RequestBin.

RequestBin doesn't provide API for you to catch the responses. It is built for manual testing where a person checks the data using their UI.

If you wish to check the response, register a WebHook with the company that points to your server where your app resides.